# Windows Scripting can't find reference

Tags: com, vbscript, wsh

I have a windows script file that doesn't work anymore.

The script look like this

```
<job>
    <reference object="Some.Component.1" />
    <script language="VBScript">

x = CreateObject("Some.Component.1")
MsgBox TypeName(x)

    </script>
</job>
```

When I run the script with cscript or wscript I get the error

> Windows Script Host: Cannot find the type library for this reference :
>   Some.Component.1

The error code is 0x80040068 which means "Invalid index". (I tried to removed the `.1` index but it didn't work)

The strange thing is that if I remove the line `<reference object="Some.Component.1"/>`, the CreateObject line works and the object is created.

I know the script worked about a year ago. The "Some.Component" library has been updated but since CreateObject works I have no idea what is wrong with it.

I have tested the script on Server 2008 R2 (64bit), Server 2003 (32bit) and Windows 7 (64bit) with the same error.

Some.Component is 32 bit. For the 64bit machines I used cscript, wscript in the SysWow64 folder.

(I need the `<reference../>` to access enums within the component)

Comment: Could it be the version number has changed? You can specify it  at the end of the ProgID (as you have done) or as an explicit attribute `<reference [object="progID"|guid="typelibGUID"] [version="version"] />` [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/479dafxb(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Version is still 1.0. Tried specifying it explicit but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type library is not registered. This is a different and separate thing from the object being registered. Usually the control will do both.

I suggest you first try unregistering and re-registering the DLL.

```
regsvr32.exe /u c:\path\to\control.dll
regsvr32.exe c:\path\to\control.dll
```

If that doesn't work, try using RegTLib.exe to register the type library (`*.tlb`) directly.

```
regtlib.exe c:\path\to\control.dll
```

OR

```
regtlib.exe c:\path\to\control.tlb
```

Note that the type library may be a separate file or may be embedded in the DLL.

For more on regTLib.exe see here:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292744

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know I tested regsvr32 but I didn't know about regtlib. I have changed job since then so I can't test it. Maybe it helps someone else so I mark it as answer.