# Cannot find the type library for this reference

Tags: com, vbscript, msxml, wsh

I'm having troubles registering windows script file. When I'm trying to do so it says "Cannot find the type library for this reference Some.Reference"

Basically, behaviour is very similar to one described in this question [Windows Scripting can't find reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256920/windows-scripting-cant-find-reference?answertab=votes#comment8732645_7256920) but I can't figure out what to use instead of c:\path\to\control.dll.

In my case Some.Reference is Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.4.0. so what should I actually do? I tried to use different kinds of msxml.dll, but it didn't seem to help.

Or maybe there are other ways to solve this issue?

One more detail: I managed to register this script on Windows7 but I get described error in Windows Server 2008 sp 2

Comment: XML version 4 had some fairly nasty security issues, I don't have it installed anymore either on my Win8 machine.  Try 6.0.  The type library for it is registered in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221}\6.0\0

Answer (score 0):

Hans, thanks for your comment, because what I did is I used this tool
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html to view registered dlls and I found that the only abailable object I had is Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0 so I just changed my script to use this version, and as I can see from your comment it was not the worst decision